# What is the most efficient mine setup in Minecraft 1.14.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m wondering what the most efficient mine setup in 1.14.4? By this, I do not mean strip mining techniques and so forth, but actually how long you should make a strip mine before you move on to the next one, how big you should make the mining area, etc. More of a structure setup recommendation rather than the overall mining technique.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of a very old question, because the only relevant things that are new are: 1. Crawling: Super slow, definitely does not make you faster, except if you use a very slow pickaxe (because of the 33% increase in uncovered blocks per mined block). 2. Underwater caves: Doesn't matter much when strip-mining. 3. Water stuff like Dolphin's grace and so on: Doesn't really matter if you avoid underwater caves.

Comment: I changed the question a bit and added some things that weren't covered in the duplicate you linked. I'm asking more about the structure of the mine rather than a mining technique now. I hope this question can be reopened. Thanks.

Comment: How long your line should be: As long as possible. Because if you make a hundred short lines, you have to walk at least 25 blocks to start the next one. But at some point your inventory will be full, even if you use shulker boxes, ender chests, etc. "how big you should make the mining area": I don't understand that. You're not digging out an area, but lines. And the more, the better of course.

Comment: The mining area would refer to a main area to where I would branch off of.

Comment: @FabianRöling: That's a deep fallacy. If you make a 1000 blocks long line you will have to walk 1000 blocks back to unload your inventory, then return 1000 blocks to the end to continue the line, then return 2000 blocks... Nonsense. It's much smarter to make a U turn after a time and dig back to start. What distance? Subject to analysis. This is also why I nominate this question for reopening.

Comment: Thanks for the support SF. What would you say is a good mining distance to start with?

Comment: i was thinking a good layout would be a central room that is square and then on the four corners make large tunnels and strip mine on each tunnels. What would be good dimensions for those?

Comment: Alright, let's reopen this. But I disagree with the U turn, there are more efficient ways to return. Like Nether, elytra rocket boost, ender pearl station, ender chest+death, … In the long term, the path to travel to the beginning of the new mining line matters. And that is a problem that just grows and grows over time.

Comment: If you're on a mining expedition, I don't think there's a more efficient way to return than to mine your way back, 2 blocks over. And the travel down the main corridor to/from cache will grow very slowly if your branches are sufficiently long.